# How to include Css in Express js in Node js

Tags: html, css, node.js, express

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

in main.js

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
```

in html

but its still not loading css

my path

```
.web
. public/
.  css/
.   style.css
. main.js
. pages/
.  index.html
```

Comment: Did the answers solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Crucial Line in index.js file:

```
app.use("/", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));
```

As we Can read in `express` [docs](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html):

> "It’s safer to use the absolute path of the directory that you want to
> serve."

And here You have my simple example:

**File & folder** structure:

[image]

**index.js**

```
const path = require("path");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.use("/", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "pages/index.html"));
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is  listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, viewport-fit=cover"
    />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
    <title>Express and Css</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Example => Express with static files.Css and favicon!</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

**style.css**

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Share+Tech+Mono&display=swap");

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-family: "Share Tech Mono", monospace;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: #000;
  color: red;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

**Output** in browser:

[image]